# All my funds are showing up as unconfirmed. What can I do?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, multibit-hd

[image]

The last transactions were taking a lot of time to confirm and now I find my funds are unconfirmed. What is happening? What can i do?
Thank you for your help

Comment: @utf-8: Not a duplicate: The transactions date back to last year and are unconfirmed. I think it's a bug in MultiBitHD instead.